# Can't get landscape bounds for modal UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a landscape view which is activated via listening for orientation notifications and then presenting a modal view controller.

However, it's giving me some grief.

It seems whatever I do I just can't seem to get landscape bounds.

super.view.bounds is {{0, 0}, {320, 480}} portrait, even though it is drawing at the correct orientation.

Help me please! Close to cardiac arrest...

Comment: Landscape activated via listening for orientation notifications? Do you mean by using [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; and then listening for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notifications? And how do you rotate your 'normal' view?

Comment: Yes, by using [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

The 'normal' view stays as is, the modal landscape controller is overridden to only support landscape views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that as my modal controller was a navigation controller, the correct bounds could be reached via:

```
CGRect bounds = self.navigationController.view.bounds;
```